# how to access a file with restricted permissions using a diffrent software?

Tags: permissions, ssh

I want to upload a file from my .ssh folder to a website, I can modify it using sudo in the terminal, but it is not getting uploaded, probably because the browser does not have enough privilege to access the file. So how do I upload this file, given that this is a SSH key, I don't want to change the root permission of the file itself.

Comment: I as the user have access and can use sudo to modify or copy paste it, but when it comes to access from a 3rd party software, it cannot access the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it's the **public key** you want to upload ...

---

Every user (including the software a user is running) has read access to his ssh keys.
Private key should have `-rw-------`, public key should have `-rw-r--r--`.

You might want to fix your setup.

---

If you cannot fix your setup you can alternatively copy the file to some temporary location. Change its permissions, upload the file and remove the temporary copy again:

```
sudo cp /path/to/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ~/Desktop
sudo chmod a+r ~/Desktop/id_rsa.pub

# Upload file

sudo rm ~/Desktop/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: Can it be done without copying the file or modifying the file in any way i.e. by elevating the software's permission or something?

Comment: the software has the same permissions as the user running it. You might run the software with root rights, but I'd strongly advice not to do that.